# Name of specific recursive function

Tags: function, recursion

Is there a specific name for this recursive function? It slightly resembles Ackermann's function, but this seems different. Any ideas?

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Basic_version

[image]

Comment: It is Ackermann's function

Comment: Interesting. Is there a code example for such a function?

Comment: You can get coding sample in whichever language you want over here. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: I'm confused, because the function listed on Rosetta Code, looks different from the function posted here. How would this translate to Ackermann? Sorry, if I sound ill informed.

Comment: @user3632894 No, it's not.

Comment: @melpomene Any suggestions?

Comment: @cosmoo No, sorry. I can see it's not the Ackermann function because `A(0, 0) = 1` whereas `foo(0, 0) = 0` (and it doesn't contain the nested `A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1))` call), but I don't recognize it.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, certainly not Ackermann's, the first response further confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version of the recursion, it works accurately. I still was not able to find a name for the function.

```
int foo (int x, int y) {            
    if (x <= 0) {return y;}
    if (y <= 0) {return x;}

    if (x >= y) {
        return x + foo(x - 2, y);
    }

    if (x < y) {
        return y + foo(x, y - 3);
    }
}
```